# jQuery remove certain tags from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string where I want to remove all figure tags.  I have tried the following:

```
var s = '<html><body>report content<figure id="fig2" data-contenttype="chart"><img src="chart.jpg"/><div>chart 1</div></figure><div>body content</div><figure id="fig2"><img src="chart2.jpg"/><div>chart 2</div></figure></body></html>';
var result = $(s).find('figure').remove();
```

The reason this does not work is that find does not find the figure elements because they have children.  Does anyone know how I can remove all figure nodes (and everything inside them) and leave the rest of the html in tact?

Note the html is not in the DOM I need to do this via string manipulation.  I don't want to touch the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `string` in a jQuery object and do some sort of a manipulation like this:

```
var removeElements = function(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector).remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var removedString = removeElements('<html><body>report content<figure id="fig2" data-contenttype="chart"><img src="chart.jpg"/><div>chart 1</div></figure><div>body content</div><figure id="fig2"><img src="chart2.jpg"/><div>chart 2</div></figure></body></html>','figure');
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can specify a jquery selector which to remove.

**Another approach for keeping html and body tag:**

```
var s = '<html><body>report content<figure id="fig2" data-contenttype="chart"><img src="chart.jpg"/><div>chart 1</div></figure><div>body content</div><figure id="fig2"><img src="chart2.jpg"/><div>chart 2</div></figure></body></html>';
var $s = s.replace(/<figure>(.*)<\/figure>/g, "");
console.log($s)
```

Comment: still body will be lost... the difficulty in this problem was that part.... the html parser does not respect the html and body tags

Comment: Thanks that works. as @ArunPJohny says it does remove the html and body tags but I can add those back in.  Cheers.

Comment: @KevinHolditch:i have added another apporoach. This will even prevent reappending html and body tag.